# Estou criando flap bir pelo o pygame e a animação nao esta funcionando bem

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Então seguinte como ja disse no titulo estou cria um flap bird , ainda nao implementei fisica e os tubos porem o meu problema esta sendo com a animação dele , oque está acontecendo é que ele só faz a animação o passaro quando eu passo mouse na tela e não tenho ideia do que está acontecendo .
 Ressaltando que ainda sou iniciante na programação pode ser um erro bobo.

```
import pygame

import neat

import time

import os

import random


WIN_WIDTH = 500

WIN_HEIGTH = 800

BIRD_IMG = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('imgs','bird1.png'))),pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('imgs','bird2.png'))),pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('imgs','bird3.png')))]

PIPE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('imgs','pipe.png')))

BASE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('imgs','base.png')))

BG_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('imgs','bg.png')))


class Bird:
    IMGS = BIRD_IMG

    MAX_RATATION = 25

    ROT_VEL = 20

    ANIMATION_TIME = 5


    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tilt = 0
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.vel = 0
        self.height = self.y
        self.img_count = 0
        self.img = self.IMGS[0]

    def Jump(self):
        self.vel = -10.5
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.height = self.y

    def move(self):
        self.tick_count += 1

        d = self.vel*self.tick_count + 1.5*self.tick_count**2

        if d >= 16:
            d = 16
        if d < 0:
            d -= 2
        self.y = self.y + d
        if d < 0 or self.y < self.height + 50:
            if self.tilt < self.MAX_RATATION:
                self.tilt = self.MAX_RATATION
        else:
            if self.tilt > -90:
                self.tilt -= self.ROT_VEL

    def draw(self,win):

        self.img_count += 1

        if self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME:
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*2:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*3:
            self.img = self.IMGS[2]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*4:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count == self.ANIMATION_TIME*4 + 1:
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
            self.img_count = 0
        if self.tilt <= -80:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
            self.img_count = self.ANIMATION_TIME*2

        rotated_image =  pygame.transform.rotate(self.img, self.tilt)

        bew_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center=self.img.get_rect(topleft= (self.x, self.y)).center)

        win.blit(rotated_image, bew_rect.topleft)



    def get_mask(self):

        return pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)

def draw_window(win, bird):

    win.blit(BG_IMG,(0,0))

    bird.draw(win)

    pygame.display.update()




def main():

    bird = Bird(200,200)

    win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGTH))

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()


    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(30)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = false
            bird.move()
            draw_window(win,bird)


    pygame.quit()
    quit()
main()
```

Comment: Atualizei a resposta conforme a dica dada pelo @jsbueno!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de tudo, vamos entender como as coisas funcionam no Python.

#### Definição de blocos de código

Como você já deve estar sabendo (mas que não custa nada relembrar), no Python, os blocos de código para certas estruturas (`if`, `else`, `for`, `while` etc.) são definidas, "delimitadas", com as chamadas indentações, que podem consistir em *tabs* (tabulações), ou *espaços*, no início da linha. Quando são *espaços*, geralmente, vai de 2 a 4 espaços. Assim:

```
print("Antes do 'if'")
n = int(input("Digite um número: "))

if n > 5:
    print("Dentro do 'if'")
    print(n)

print("Fora do 'if'")
```

Tudo que está depois de `if n > 5:` e possui a chamada indentação (que expliquei acima) é considerado dentro do `if`. E tudo que está depois de `if n > 5:` e não possui a indentação é considerado fora do `if`. Ou seja:

```
if n > 5:
    # só executa se 'n' for maior que 5
    print("Dentro do 'if'")
    print(n)

# vai executar independente de 
# 'n' ser maior que 5, ou não
print("Fora do 'if'")
```

Assim também funciona nas estruturas `for`, assim como `while`:

```
print("Antes do 'for'")

for i in range(10):
    if i % 2 == 0: # se for par
        print("Par:", i)
    elif i % 2 == 1: # se for ímpar
        print("Ímpar:", i)

    print("Analisado o {}º número".format(i+1))

print("Fora do 'for'")
```

O que está depois de `for i in range(10)` e está indentado, é considerado parte do `for`. E o que não está indentado, é considerado fora do `for`. E no bloco `if-elif` aplica-se a mesma coisa.

Feita essa revisão, vamos ao problema.

### Por que só atualiza a animação quando coloco o cursor (do mouse) na tela?

O que está acontecendo é que você só está atualizando a tela quando algum evento (seja do mouse, seja do teclado) acontece:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
```

Ou seja: *para cada evento que tiver ocorrido, faça isso*. E se não tiver nenhum evento? Então, ele não faz!

Por isso que:

```
    # essas linhas
    bird.move()
    draw_window(win, bird)
```

Têm que estar **fora** do `for`, ou seja:

```
run = True
while run:
     clock.tick(30)
     for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             run = false

     # fora do 'for', porém dentro do 'while' (loop de execução)
     # executando assim, independente de ter
     # ocorrido um evento, ou não
     bird.move()
     draw_window(win,bird)

pygame.quit()
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: tem que tirar o `bird.move`  do `for event...` tambem.  Consegue arrumar aí?

Comment: No caso, eu tinha ficado um pouco em dúvida em relação a essa linha! Mas, sim, eu corrijo! Obrigado pela dica @jsbueno!

Comment: Muito obrigado Gustavo, sua explicação me ajudou a tirar algumas duvidas que eu sempre tive , eu estou aprendendo python meio autodidata paguei um curso de basico de python porém era entediante pois sou o tipo de pessoa que aprende mais fazendo do que lendo a teoria (sim, eu sei teoria é importante para a programção) mas estou aprendendo mais tentando fazer o flap bird do que fazendo um curso sobre logica., pois na pratica faz muito mais sentido e mais uma vez obrigado por ter me ensinado